# What ArcGIS Online feature service provides European states with unique country codes?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, arcgis-online, feature-service

I'm writing a web page to display ECB statistics on an ArcGIS JavaScript API-based web map.

I'm a bit lost when selecting a feature service so that I can use the UniqueValueRenderer to make the states pretty colors according to their statistics.

Is there a feature service available on ArcGIS Online that I can use for this?

Comment: What web API (ArcGIS API for JavaScript, Flex, Silverlight, or Web ADF) are you using, assuming you are using one (try not to leave so much to guessing...)?

Comment: Also have a look at the [tag wiki](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-layer/info) for the `feature-layer` tag which I just added.

Comment: Okay now that that's cleared up, what do you mean by "selecting a feature layer"? There is only one [`FeatureLayer`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/#featurelayer) class in the ArcGIS JavaScript API.

Comment: Also have a look at the [Use a unique value renderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/renderer_unique_value) sample.

Comment: Selecting a feature layer means finding one that will be used with the UniqueValueRenderer class to selectively color states based upon their name or their two character international code, such as DK or Germany.

Comment: So this is not a "how do I use the API" question, but a "where do I get this data" question, is that accurate?

Comment: Do you have your own ArcGIS Server instance, or were you planning on using ArcGIS Online?

Comment: It's a what feature layer (data) do I use question.

Comment: Using ArcGIS online.

Comment: I have edited your question to make that clear. Hopefully now someone can help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this layer works well.

https://services.arcgis.com/HuLaMAzbcrbWfOM8/ArcGIS/rest/services/Outline_of_world_countries/FeatureServer/0

field name is Country and the countries are their English names.  Ie: Germany and Spain.

Comment: You may want to use the term "feature service" when referring to such data sources. A feature layer is the client side representation, while a feature service is the server side service providing the data.

Comment: So much to learn.  Good thing you are here number 238 Blah.